# Create a set from a string of elements in Rego

Tags: open-policy-agent, rego

How to create a set from a string in Rego Open Policy Agent language?

I've a string of elements like `"values": "pvc-volume,emptydir-volume,hostPath,ConfigMaps"` which elements  need to be validated against a given set of admitted values

```
valid_backup_profiles := {
      "pvc-volume",
      "emptydir-volume"
    }
```

for example using intersection

`valid_backup_profiles & elements_coming_from_string_above`

I know the `split(string, ",")` function returning an array of elements but the array cannot be intersected with a set. Is there any smart way to generate a set from a string instead of an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to use a [set comprehension](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/policy-language/#comprehensions):

```
s := {x |
  some i
  parts := split(string, ",")
  x := parts[i]
}
```

You can do it on one line like this if you want:

`s := {x | x := split(string, ",")[_]}`

Obviously this is nice and compact, but the form above is a bit easier to read. If you want to make the logic reusable, just define a function:

```
split_csv_set(str) = {x |
  some i
  parts := split(str, ",")
  x := parts[i]
}
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. Do you think a `split_to_set(string, "delimiter")` or whatever function can be added to the standard rego library?

Comment: @kalise see the updated version. that defines a function. You can do this yourself inside Rego.